# Post Form - I Didn't Receive Email

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I can understand tags a bit, also I´ve successfully edited a CMS named GetSimple and all works fine (few months ago). Now, after a couple of months I´ve started with this and cant go through...

I've got the massage of a successful send... "Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon. " but I didn't receive the mail. I've tried different HTML and PHP examples from the internet, but it's the same problem.

HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="send.php" class="left" enctype="text/plain">
    <input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
    <fieldset>
        <label for="your_name">YOUR NAME *</label><input type="text"  id="your_name" name="your_name" class="required" /><br/>
        <label for="your_email">YOUR email *</label><input type="text" id="your_email" name="your_email" class="required email" /><br/>
        <label for="current_site">current site</label><input type="text" id="current_site" name="current_site" /><br/>
        <label for="estimated_budget">estimated budget</label><input type="text" id="estimated_budget" name="estimated_budget" /><br/>
        <label for="project_description">project description</label> <textarea id="project_description" name="project_description"></textarea><br/>
        <!--<input type="submit" value="send" id="sendbutton">  -->
        <button class="defaultButton small" id="quotebutton"><span class="buttonLabel">Send</span></button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP named "send.php"

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {


    $email_to = "mymail@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "example subject";



    $your_name = $_POST['your_name']; // required
    $your_email = $_POST['your_email']; // required

    $error_message = "Please enter valid e-mail adress";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($your_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Mail: ".clean_string($your_email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Current site: ".clean_string($current_site)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Estimated budget: ".clean_string($estimated_budget)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Project description: ".clean_string($project_description)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$your_email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$your_email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
 } 
<!-- place your own success html below -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
die();
?>
```

Comment: Mail function in php returns true or false status after mail sending.Check it

Comment: `enctype="text/plain"` — WTF? Why would you use that? *Payloads using the text/plain format are intended to be human readable. **They are not reliably interpretable by computer***! — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#text/plain-encoding-algorithm

Comment: Remove the "@" infront of the mail function and let us know what you get. @ supresses warning and errors.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran removed, but still nothing. Btw how I can check that true or false status?

Answer (score 2):

According to your script, the submit button need to contain name value 'email'

```
<input type="submit" value="send" id="sendbutton">
```

so the fix is:

```
<input type="submit" value="send" name="email" id="sendbutton" />
```

Remove the html note tags from your form.
the full code:

```
<form method="POST" action="send.php" class="left" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="hidden" name="form-name" value="contact" />
<fieldset>
    <label for="your_name">YOUR NAME *</label><input type="text"  id="your_name" name="your_name" class="required" /><br/>
    <label for="your_email">YOUR email *</label><input type="text" id="your_email" name="your_email" class="required email" /><br/>
    <label for="current_site">current site</label><input type="text" id="current_site" name="current_site" /><br/>
    <label for="estimated_budget">estimated budget</label><input type="text" id="estimated_budget" name="estimated_budget" /><br/>
    <label for="project_description">project description</label> <textarea id="project_description" name="project_description"></textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="email" value="send" id="sendbutton">
</fieldset>
```

Comment: still not working, also tried to remove @ from php document as  @ShankarDamodaran said

Comment: the $email_to contains your email? remove the enctype from the form tag. maybe you can found some errors in the apache log..

Comment: yes, there is my mail, also removed enctype and still the same problem

Comment: is it a home server? (Wamp, XAMPP) I think the problem is the SMTP protocol. please check in the logs of apache if there are any errors about the mail() function.

Comment: nah, www.kokociny.ic.cz, I´ve tested form about an year ago with this host and it worked fine, but i cant remember how I did it.

Comment: Please, try to put the mail function into if statement. if it returns false something gone wrong with the function.. and if can, add in the top of the script error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 2):

First i think your missing some headers look at those

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

2nd check if its true or false when calling the mail function

```
if( mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)!==true)
    {
        die('Fail to send');


    }
    die('Sucess');

    }
```