# PHP Contact Form Not Sending Email

Tags: php, html-email

I'm writing to create a contact form on my website and then get the information sent to my inbox, however it is not working whatsoever. Please take a look at my code below (PHP is not my thing) and let me know where i've gone wrong.

Here's the PHP script:

```
<?php

$to = 'example@gmail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$project = $_POST['project'];
$range1 = $_POST['range1'];
$range2 = $_POST['range2'];

$body = <<<EMAIL

Hi, my name is $name.

I'd like to discuss the possibility of working together on a $project.

My budget for the project is £$range1 and I would like to complete the project within $range2 Month(s).

Additional Information:
$message

Regards, $name

<hr>
$name
$email
$tel

EMAIL;

$header = "From: $email";

if($_POST['send']){
mail($to, $subject, $body, $header);
$feedback = 'Thank you for your message, we will get back to you shortly.';
}

?>
```

And here's the HTML form:

```
<form id="form_id" name="form_name" action="" method="post">

  <div>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required/>
  </div>
<div>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
  </div>
<div>
<input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Phone" required/>
  </div>

<div>
  <select required id="project">
<option selected>Select type of project…</option>
<option value="Responsive Website">Responsive Web Design</option>
<option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
<option value="Motion Graphics">Motion Graphics</option>
  </select> 
</div>

  <div>
<label for="range1">Budget: </label>
<input type="range" name="range1" id="range1" min="400" max="2000" step="50" value="6" required onchange="rangevalue.value=value"><output id="rangevalue">400</output>
  </div>

<div>
<label for="range2">Timeframe: </label>
<input type="range" name="range2" id="range2" min="1" max="12" step=".5" value="1" required onchange="rangevalue1.value=value"><output id="rangevalue1">1</output>
  </div>

<div>
<label for="message">Additional Information: </label><br/>
<p>(Please use this space to tell us about your company, the main objectives of the proposed website and anything else you think might be useful)</p>
<textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" cols="30" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
  </div>

<div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>

</form>
<p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
```

Thanks for the help. FYI this can be achieved easily with WordPress through Contact Form 7 (or a similar plugin).

Comment: Is mail() enabled on your server?

Comment: make suer error checking and display are on, check what mail() returns, check the mail server logs.

Comment: where is the $_POST['send'] in your form ?

Comment: Like i said guys, i am a total newbie to PHP, i've used this php form, although a MUCH simpler version (To, Email, Name, Message) and it's worked fine :/

Comment: look at my answer, go here http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp , then you should get back, your missing essencial PHP basis that you should understand, its for your own good.

Comment: Mail is an intermediate topic at best, you have to know about headers and stuff...maybe save this project for a different day and learn some more PHP first?

Comment: @konnection and anyone else who uses W3Schools - http://w3fools.com/

Comment: @Steve, why is that? W3Schools have a very good introduction to PHP, and i'm sure that if the user that did this question have read the page, this question didn't exist at all. But instead of doing those comments, try to help giving better paces for him to learn!

Comment: Why is what? W3Schools is notorious for its errors and is one of the main reasons web developers and PHP are looked at as the dogs of the programming world.  Bad code architecture, poor standards, and coders who don't give a hoot about either one.  The founder of StackOverflow seems to agree: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/php-sucks-but-it-doesnt-matter.html and http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/06/the-php-singularity.html.  For better places to learn, look on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610543/recommended-way-to-learn-php

Comment: Or, if you're asking "why does W3Schools suck", did you read the page?  This line is great, from W3School's footer: `We do not warrant the correctness of [W3Schools] content. The risk from using it lies entirely with the user.`

Comment: Further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803018/is-w3schools-a-valid-reference  I'm seriously not trying to troll.  There's the right way to do things, and the other way.  W3Schools misleads its audience (who are often beginners), period.

Comment: Guys come on cut it out. I appreciate the help from all of you. The best thing about the web industry is the web community so let's not fight amongst ourselves.

Comment: @Steve, well i don't think its the perfect place to learn, and i didn't say that it doesnt have errors, but for the needs of the user in question i think its more than enougth, and thanks for the links very helpfull indeed.

Comment: @Yvette - not insulting anyone.  Downvotes exist for poor answers, it's not a personal thing.  Rumman - sorry about this.  Like I said before, not trying to troll, honestly trying to help.  Welcome to SO (it's not always like this :)), and don't forget to accept an answer ;).

Comment: @Yvette, you can learn the basics from there without any problem in my point of view, but you may want to take a look at the Steve links aswell, and other resources too, it will only help you ;)

Comment: @Steve I've updated my answer, it now points the links of our discussion, this will help others to stay alert for the w3schools mistakes, and to search for other alternatives .

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610543/recommended-way-to-learn-php), be aware that despite W3Schools may serve as a basics tutorial because of the friendly-user examples, always complement with other resources [look here why](http://w3fools.com).

Then you can take a look at this answers, this is just because you need some more basis to understand everything you are doing.

I can't see your $_POST['send'] name in the form, or it's just too late and I'm tired:

Don't know, but maybe, you want this in your form before the submit:

```
<input type="hidden" name="send" >
```

Then:

I already posted this answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333670/post-form-i-didnt-receive-email/16336734#16336734), but here it is:

**First i think your missing some headers look at those**

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
```

**2nd check if its true or false when calling the mail function**

```
if( mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)!==true)
    {
        die('Fail to send');


    }
    die('Success');

    }
```

You should take a look at the [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)  function to make sure all your variables are set from the form.

Comment: Ok guys thanks for your help, the forms working but I have a <select> dropdown and the selected option is not appearing in the email?

Comment: change the id to name in the select <select name="project" required>

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
```

You have to change this line to:

```
<input type="submit" name="send" value="submit" />



  if($_POST['send']){
```

actually checking if submit button is clicked...

And, yes - if html and php are on different pages, you have to set proper form action link...